# How to edit /etc/sysconfig/iptables from: RESCUE MODE boot?

Tags: startup

Let's say the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` needs to be edited because, due to it I can not ssh to my server.

I start my server in "Rescue Mode", but when I login, there is no such thing as `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` to edit.

What can be done so I can edit that file from this rescue mode? Or at least, is there a way to reboot the system while ensuring, `iptables` is not started, while inside of the rescue mode?

Comment: Have you tried the grub trick `init=bash`... `# mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: @user79634 please update the question with what distro and version you are using. And also the details of configuration changes you might have made earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CD with an installation image or a rescue system image, then boot that, mount the root partition and edit whatever you need.

Answer (score -2):

init=/bin/bash

But you may try to boot in "single user" mode by adding command "1" to boot loader at boot time. Looks like:

kernel /boot/vmlin...  1

All filesystems will be mounted automatically in normal mode. Then you may fix your /etc/sysconfig/iptables config file.

http://www.tecmint.com/linux-kernel-boot-time-parameters-explained/
http://redsymbol.net/linux-kernel-boot-parameters/

Comment: I guess you should clearly read the question first. I didnt find even the word `iptables` in those links.

Comment: Oops...
/root is mounted but no config found. Is it correct?
Very strange. But if you sure iptables has block network access you may add `exit` as a second line in `/etc/init.d/iptables` and restart.